# Как правильно организовать очередь для обновлений?

Tags: очередь, php

Много думал, но так пока и не придумал.
**Дано в теории:**
Есть 2 базы. В одной список пользователей с общей статистикой, во второй более подробная статистика по каждому пользователю (читай подробнейший лог).
Таблица со списком пользователей, например:

```
1 Вася
2 Петя
3 Женя
```

**Что надо:**
Как сделать так, что если данные по Васе запрашивают чаще, то обновлять эту запись в первой базе чаще, т.е. чтобы иметь более актуальные данные по более часто запрашиваемым пользователям, а те, кого реже запрашивают -- реже актуализировать данные.

В теории я так понимаю надо иметь поле в первой базе с последним временем запроса.

Может кто имел такой опыт, может статьи какие, мож для гугла правильный запрос составить :) Просто пока даже в теории логику не могу придумать, пните в каком направлении думать.

---

Придумал пример. В принципе отчасти он правдив, по крайней мере про картинки :)

Есть онлайн игра. Есть бэкенд базаданных, где все хранится в подробном виде. Я хочу пользователям сделать userbars с их какойто статистикой. Соответственно постоянно тягать и рассчитывать данные из рабочей базы совершенно не хочется по понятным причинам. Для этого я хочу сделать отдельную базу данных и в нее время от времени вытаскивать данные из боевой базы. Если Васина картинка тягается достаточно часто, то обновлять его данные раз в 1 час, а Петину картинку посмотрели всего один раз за час, то обновлять его данные раз в 3 часа, а если в итоге его картинку посмотрели всего один раз в день, то обновлять его раз в 6 часов, ну и если чтото меняется в просмотразх, то обновлять его чаще/реже.

Comment: наверное не последнее время запроса а частоту надо хранить, причем надо наверное как-то локальную частоту хранить, может даже несколько частот, чтобы при активации просмотра данных по Васе, актуализировать данные быстрее, чем 20 раз они будут запрошены. (короче это наверное называется рейтинг запроса данных)

Comment: А как так получается, что у Вас данные о пользователе могут обновляться только в какой-то момент? Как я понял, то вся деятельность пользователя должна в этот же момент записываться в базу данных, а при запросе данных об этом пользователе другими пользователями, выбирать все данные(причем они будут всегда актуальны)... Объясните может я суть вопроса не так понял и это все делается для других целей...

Comment: во, вот это ближе к теме.

Comment: в linux кстати есть похожая тема - load average называется.

Comment: дополнил вопрос примером :)  
имхо load average в линукс другое...

Comment: la как раз то самое - сколько раз юзер был посмотрен за периоды времени. из этого  можно посчитать вес юзера, потом рандомайзером с весами раз в скажем, 10 минут считать, например, 10 рандомных юзеров (рандомайзер сдвигается в зависимости от веса юзера)

Comment: хм, да, идея хороша. В этом ключе както не подумал про load average. Теперь бы еще найти чегонить про это почитать :)

Comment: Так а решили что-то? На чем остановились? )

Comment: Пока что остановился на варианте
есть поле последнего обновления, в скрипте захардкожен лимит 15, из базы берется 15 записей с датой последнего обновления старше чем 15 минут... Крон запускается раз в 4 минуты... Впринципе пока хватает, записей не очень много.

Answer (score 3):

Я вот что придумал: в первой базе сделать подсчет количества просмотра профиля. Потом высчитывать по общему по формуле вида:

```
первое_знач = кол-во_просмотров_одного/общее_кол-во_просмотров * 100.
```

Потом, допустим, взять 1 час.

```
1 час = 100%. 1 минута_проц = 1.(6)%
```

И в конце получаем кол-во обновлений в час для одного:

```
кол-во_обновлений_в_час = floor(первое_знач/минута_проц).
```

О как.

Comment: Мне почемуто кажется, что правильнее через время высчитывать, завязать это както на дату последнего просмотра и дату последнего обновления  

Но за идею спасибо.

Comment: @thunder хм, а что, если профиль с посещаемостью 10 раз в год (в среднем), я зашел перед обновлением статистики. А на профиль с посещаемостью 10 раз в день (в среднем) никто не заходил 2 дня? Мне не кажется, что правильнее через время считать.

Comment: лимитировать обновления к примеру раз в 3 дня

Comment: т.е. постепенно снижать его приоритет в обновлении.

Answer (score 3):

Мне сначала на ум пришло нечто вроде [`rrd`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRD), но прикинул, что это слишком сложно будет, да и не в полной мере соответствует задаче.

На деле задача может решиться относительно просто. Вам достаточно запоминать время последнего и предпоследнего просмотров профиля. Т.е. при очередном просмотре вы просто записываете значение последнего просмотра в предпоследнее, а на место времени последнего просмотра пишете текущее время.

При выборке данных делаете следующее. Пусть

```
t1 = текущее_время - время_последнего_просмотра,
t2 = время_последнего_просмотра - время_предпоследнего_просмотра,
```

и все это дело изменяется, например, в часах (можно с дробями). Тогда

```
dt1 = 1 / t1
dt2 = 1 / t2
```

Грубо выражаясь, мы находим некую динамику скорости просмотра :)

Здесь физический смысл единицы в числителе - кол-во просмотров за этот период. Т.к. у нас обновление происходит при каждом просмотре, то это количество соответственно равно единице.

Простейшим вариантом подсчета нужного вам коэффициента будет простое среднее последних чисел:

```
x = (dt1 + dt2) / 2
```

Здесь вы можете применить любую функцию, какая вам больше понравится. Разные функции будут выдавать разную зависимость от этих параметров.

В принципе, для более качественной зависимости результата от частоты просмотров профиля можно

- запоминать больше меток времени. Большее кол-во исключит всплески флуктуации, хотя с другой стороны, мне кажется, более пяти меток запоминать смысла нет;
- попробовать квантировать временнЫе отрезки и запоминать кол-во просмотров за этот промежуток, например за час, и это количество подставлять там в числителе вместо единицы (правда тогда помимо меток времени, нужно будет еще хранить и это количество, да и в целом *это более геморный способ*).

Пробуйте разные варианты, анализируйте результаты и подскажите нам вариант, на котором остановитесь :)

Comment: Спасибо за вариант.